# C++ Builder: Pass Onclick-Event of Button on Form1 to Button on Form2

Tags: c++, pointers, events, c++builder

I have two Forms called Form1 and Form2. In Form1 I have two buttons and one Label. One Button to open Form2 by calling `Form2->Show()`.
The second Button sets the Caption of Label1 in Form1 to e.g. "Hello world".
In Form2 I have another button and Label. The button in Form2 sets the Label in Form2 to "Hello universe".
I like to pass the OnClick-Event of the Button in Form1 to the OnClick-Event of the Button in Form2.
That means, when I click on the Button in Form1, the Label in Form1 should be set to "Hello world" and immediately fires the OnClick-event in Form2 to set its Label to "Hello universe".

That should be done not by calling the OnClick-Event of Form2 in the OnClick-event in Form1. That would be too easy. Instead I like to assign it from Form2. Something like `Button1->OnClick = Form1->Button1->OnClick`

Is there any way to realize it?

Thanks

Christian

Comment: So, you basically want to execute more than one event handler when clicking `Button1` in `Form1`? That is not possible. You'll need to do it manually.

Comment: @TedLyngmo well, it is *possible*, but it is not something that is built in, it has to be setup manually. For example, [like this](https://blog.therealoracleatdelphi.com/2008/08/multicast-events-using-generics_15.html).

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yeah, something like that is what I had in mind.

Comment: Ok thank you! I think that way is too difficult to use it in normal process. I'll go the classic way with function pointers.
Therefore I add a container for function pointers and fill it from Form2, 3 and so on. Then I'll execute that functions in the onclick-event in Form1. The Reference to the container (e.g. a vector of type function) can be passed to method as class parameter